# Sitemap generator for popup window javascript

Tags: javascript, html, sitemap

On my HTML index page, I am using a popup javascript code that has something like

```
<li> <font color ="#000"> &#187; </font> <font color ="#ccc">
<a href="javascript: void(0)" onClick="newWindow('mypage.php','nwin','1200','850','resizable=no,scrollbars=no,status=no,toolbar=no')">Some text</a></font><b>, XYX, Country</b></li>
<li><font color ="#000"> &#187; </font><a href ="secondpage.php"   alt="Blog" />
```

I used a free xml-sitemap generator and strangely, the second li which is a regular a href URL and shows up in the sitemap as a linked page. However, the first one which calls the page using a javascript function does not show up.

This got me thinking,

1. Would this impact SEO results, would search engines also skip JS code and hence not crawl the linked pages which open in a popup?
2. Or is this an issue with the sitemap generator that does not understand JS and I have to manually create it?

Totally new to this. Was hoping to get some advise .

thanks!
Ryan

Comment: SEO? is it google crawler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answer will vary based of crawlers, but you should keep your markup readable and less dynamic in areas you want crawler to read or you can follow the guidelines provided. For specific answer to your question:

Since 2009 Google looks for and finds OnClick links in any and all HTML tags. When found they will add the URL to their crawl.

If there is sensible "anchor" text then the text of the element will be used as anchor text.

The OnClick link also passes PageRank.

For more info:
http://www.searchenginepeople.com/blog/onclick.html

http://seogadget.com/google-does-not-crawl-hidden-java-onclick/